# Cannot run JUnit-test in eclipse but with gradle

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, junit, jasper-reports

I have a gradle project in eclipse (Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)
Build id: 20170314-1500). When i execute my simple JUnit-test with gradle, everything works fine. But if i execute/debug the test in eclipse (by the context 
menu), the test crashes.

The exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError. I think the jasperreports dependency causes the crashes with a wrong CLASSPATH (?). Or the combination of gradle and eclipse does not work correctly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated:)

I have reduce the project to a minimum.

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.olap4j:olap4j:1.2.0'

    compile 'com.lowagie:itext:4.2.0'

    compile 'net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:6.4.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-bin.zip
```

ReportTest.java:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.DefaultJasperReportsContext;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReportsContext;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter;

public class ReportTest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        JasperReportsContext jasperReportsContext = DefaultJasperReportsContext.getInstance();
        JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter(jasperReportsContext);
    }
}
```

Stacktrace in eclipse:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/lowagie/text/DocumentException
    at ReportTest.test(ReportTest.java:12)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.lowagie.text.DocumentException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 24 more
```

Comment: You are using buildship in Eclipse and have imported the project as Gradle project?

Comment: Yes, i think so. In eclipse, i use in the Properties -> Builders -> Gradle Project Builder". And, yes, its a gradle project.

Comment: Maybe i can add the whole project as ZIP-file here? And, if needed, i can add the .project and .classspath files here.